# Merging a php array with an array item

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I am trying to merge an item from one array and a full array from another I cant figure out what is the best solution?

Here is what I have:

```
$name = $item['name'];
// Returns = Admin
```

The `$item['authority']` actually pulls back link this:

```
adverts,blog,comments
```

So I put them into there own array:

```
$auth = explode(",", $item['authority']); 

// Returns
array(4) {
  [0]=> string(7) "adverts"
  [1]=> string(4) "blog"
  [2]=> string(8) "comments"
  [3]=>
}
```

I want to merge them into 1 array is this possible or what would be the best solution?

```
$joined = array_merge($name, $auth);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new array:

```
$joined = array( 'name' => $name, 'auth' => $auth);
```

This will create a multidimensional array. You can't use `array_merge()` on `$name` since it's `$name` isn't an array. But, you could do:

```
$joined = array_merge( array( $name), $auth);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = $item['name'];
// Returns = Admin

$auth = explode(",", $item['authority']); 
$auth[] = $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close:

```
$joined = array_merge($name, $auth);
```

It's just that you need two arrays and `$name` is none yet:

```
$joined = array_merge(array($name), $auth);
```

This should already do it. But I am not 100% sure if I understood your question right.